# 2021年7月時点でのGoogle Colaboratory上のPythonとTensorflowのバージョンが知りたいです

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-colaboratory

2021年7月にGoogle Colaboratory上でPythonとTensorflowを使ったノートブックを作成し，正しく実行できることを確認しましたが，同じノートブックを2022年1月の現時点で実行するとTensorflowによる計算結果が異なったものとなります．

原因はGoogle Colaboratoryの環境に何らかの変更があったことだと考えられます．少なくともTensorflowのバージョンが変更されたらしいのですが，2021年7月時点での正確なバージョンがわかりません（2.5だった気がするのですが，パッチバージョンまでは正確にわかりません）．

同じ時期にGoogle Colaboratoryの実行環境をログ出力するなどしてPythonとTensorflowのバージョンをご存知の方がいらっしゃいましたら教えていただけないでしょうか．できれば，Python，Tensorflow，CUDA，cuDNNを含めたGoogle Colaboratoryの実行環境の変更履歴のような情報があるとなお助かります．よろしくお願いいたします．

Comment: 2.5系ならば, 2.5.0と考えられます。[2.5.1は 8月に](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/releases?page=2)出てるようなので

Comment: @oriri さんありがとうございます．Tensorflow2.5.1のリリース時期からすると7月時点では2.5.0で間違いなさそうですね．しかし計算結果がやはりまだ再現しないので，Pythonか別のライブラリのバージョンが違うのかもしれません．